# How to read a text file and group them in tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to do the following in python 3

I have a text file like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
.
.
```

I wanted this to be converted into groups of tuple like this

```
((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),...)
```

I have tried using

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
f.readlines()
```

but this is giving me a list of individual words.

could any one help me with this?

Comment: `tuple(tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,

```
>>> s = '''1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9'''.splitlines()
>>> tuple(tuple(int(j) for j in i.split()) for i in s)
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
```

For your case,

```
tuple(tuple(int(j) for j in i.split()) for i in f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 4):

A method using csv module -

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open('a.txt','r')
>>> c = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t') #Use the delimiter from the file , if a single space, use a single space, etc.
>>> l = []
>>> for row in c:
...     l.append(tuple(map(int, row)))
...
>>> l = tuple(l)
>>> l
(('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6'), ('7', '8', '9'))
```

Though if you do not really need the tuples , do not use them, it may be better to just leave them at list.

Both `row` and `l` in above code are initially lists.

Comment: but i am getting the output like this `(('1\t2\t3',), ('1\t2\t3',), ('1\t2\t3',), ...` when i read the file

Comment: use `delimiter='\t'` then.

Comment: could you convert this into int rather than string?

Comment: Yes you can, use `map` function. Updated the code for that.